# Force SkParagraph layout to account for ghost whitespace

Tags: c++, skia

`SkParagraph` automatically compensates for "ghostwhitespace" when shaping a paragraph. I'd like to disable this behaviour and allow the line to pushed out when whitespace is introduced.

Center alignment with current behaviour:

```
       The quick brown fox 
          ate a zesty
         hamburgerfons .
         The ‍‍‍ laughed.
```

Now adding loads of spaces after `zesty`: (desired behaviour)

```
       The quick brown fox 
   ate a zesty
         hamburgerfons .
         The ‍‍‍ laughed.
```

Notice second line pushed to the left due to all the extra whitespace.

I've modified [this CanvasKit fiddle](https://jsfiddle.skia.org/canvaskit/2aadef40e142e08509a0c83e5d87edc923ed17202d8a6f29539097a1f6740453) to illustrate. See line 40.

I've also found [this flutter issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/40648#issuecomment-532080720) that illustrates the issue.

I've gone through the Skia / SkParagraph source code many times over and can't find a way to introduce the behaviour I need.